# vue function not returning dynamic property instead showing initial value

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to make a progress bar the progress bar works fine  but its not changing text within html and keeps static 0%. N.B I am pasting here only relevant codes to avoid a large page of code.

```
<div class="progressTopBar"><div class="inner-progressBar" :style="{width: this.ProgressBar }">
@{{ getProgressBar() }}
</div></div>


//property

 data: function () {
            return {
                ProgressBar:"0%",
            }
        }


//function on change to upload and make progress

            fileSelected(e) {

                let fd = new FormData();
                fd.append('fileInput', $("#file")[0].files[0], $("#file")[0].files[0].name);

                axios.post("/admin/chatFileUpload", fd,  {
                    onUploadProgress: function (uploadEvent) {
                      this.ProgressBar = Math.round((uploadEvent.loaded / uploadEvent.total)*100) + '%';

                        $(".inner-progressBar").css("width", this.ProgressBar);
                    }
                });
            },

//getting progress bar value in text which only returns preset value 
            getProgressBar() {
                return this.ProgressBar;
            },
```

Comment: did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `getProgressBar()` a computed property instead of a method.

```
computed: {
   getProgressBar() {
       return this.progressBar;
   }
}
```

Also, you should use camel case or snake case for your variables.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the scoping of `this` in the code below:

```js
onUploadProgress: function (uploadEvent) {
  this.ProgressBar = Math.round((uploadEvent.loaded / uploadEvent.total)*100) + '%';
```

Because this is a new function it has its own `this` value, it does not use the `this` value from the surrounding code.

The simplest way to fix this is to use an arrow function:

```js
onUploadProgress: (uploadEvent) => {
  this.ProgressBar = Math.round((uploadEvent.loaded / uploadEvent.total)*100) + '%';
```

An arrow function retains the `this` value from the surrounding scope.

I also suggest getting rid of the jQuery line starting `$(".inner-progressBar")`, that shouldn't be necessary once you fix the `this` problem as it will be handled by the template instead.

Further, it's unclear why you have a `getProgressBar` method at all. If it is just going to return `ProgressBar` then you can use that directly within your template without the need for a method.